# How Can I use fork() recursively?

Tags: c, unix, process, fork

I've been programming this over and over again and I've had trouble learning how to work with fork() in order to generate child processes recursively. I started programming some pretty complicated stuff and I decided to start over again with something way more simple.

I just started learning about processes and I've had trouble understanding them. 
The program is designed to fork a tree of processes, however , I must fork from the root two processes which will fork , on the left side 3 children processes, and on the right side 4 children processes. These processes must fork 3 and 4, respectively, processes of their own.

My issue with this is that the program can fork the processes, however only one process on each side is fathering all of the children on their respective side.

Any help you could give me would be great, please tell me if I'm not being clear enough.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

/* Prototypes */
void three_children();
void four_children();

int main()
{
    pid_t process;
    int status,n;

    printf("Number of levels: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
        process = fork();
        switch (process) {
            case -1:
                printf("Error\n");
                break;
            case 0:
                if (i == 0) {
                    printf("Left\n");
                    three_children(process, status);
                } 
                if (i == 1) {
                    printf("Right\n");
                    three_children(process, status);
                }
                printf("Hi I'm a child PID: %d, my father is PPID: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                exit(0);
            default:
                printf("I'm a father PPID: %d\n", getppid());
                break;
        }
    }
}

void four_children(pid_t process, int status)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        process = fork();
        switch (process) {
            case -1:
                printf("Error\n");
                break;
            case 0:
                printf("I'm child: %d, and my father is: %d\n(four children)\n", getpid(), getppid());
                exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                printf("I'm a father process: %d\n", getpid());
                four_children(process, status);
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    wait(&status);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

void three_children(pid_t process, int status)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        process = fork();
        switch (process) {
            case -1:
                printf("Error\n");
                break;
            case 0:
                printf("I'm a child: %d, and my father is: %d\n(three children )\n", getpid(), getppid());
                exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                printf("I'm father %d\n", getpid());
                three_child(process, status);
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    wait(&status);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use English for identifiers and messages

Comment: `cuatro_hijos` = 4 children, `tres_hijos` = 3 children.

Comment: Read more about passing arguments by value. Use the result of `wait`

Comment: when a parent calls `fork()`, it receives either an error indication or the pid of the child.   Before the parent exits, it needs to call `wait()` (or better `waitpid()`).   If the parent exits before all the children exit, then those children become 'zombies'   Zombie processes cannot be removed except by rebooting the computer.  Each parent must call `wait()`  (or `waitpid()` ) for each and every child that was created by that parent,

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: in function : `main()`, the variable `status` is being passed to `three_child()`  in two places, BUT it is not initialized to any specific value AND since it is not being passed via its' address, the sub functions cannot update it.  This needs to be fixed.  Otherwise the code contains undefined behavior.  Also, `status` is not really being used anywhere, so that parameter can be eliminated, along with the declaration of `status`

Comment: no one is calling the function: `four_child()`, so the posted code has some 'dead code' and the posted code does not conform to the commentary in the OPs question.

Comment: the function: `three_child()` calls `three_child()` in every  process that is generated by `fork()`,  so there will be no limit on the number of processes generated

Comment: Sorry for not translating the code before , it was 5 am and it was a mess in 3 languages. I just corrected the prior edits. Thanks for translating.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, i will check the code when I get home, I just modified it a bit too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct Node
{   
    int             childrenCount;
    struct Node*    child[0];
} Node;

Node* makeNode(int children)
{   
    Node* result = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node) + sizeof(Node*) * children);
    if (!result) {
        exit(1);
    }   
    result->childrenCount = children;
    for(int loop = 0;loop < children; ++loop) {
        result->child[loop] = NULL;
    }   
    return result;
}   

void buildTree(int indent, pid_t parent, Node* node);
void createChild(int indent, pid_t parent, Node* node, int childIndex)
{   
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        exit(1);
    }   
    if (pid == 0) {
        buildTree(indent + 1, getpid(), node->child[childIndex]);
        srand(parent * 10  + childIndex);
        exit(rand());
    }   
    for(int ind = 0; ind < indent; ++ind) {
        fprintf(stderr, " ");
    }   
    fprintf(stderr, "Parent: %d Spawned %d\n", parent, pid);
}   

void buildTree(int indent, pid_t parent, Node* node)
{   
    for(int ind = 0; ind < indent; ++ind) {
        fprintf(stderr, " ");
    }   
    fprintf(stderr, "Parent %d Has %d Children\n", parent, node->childrenCount);
    for(int loop = 0; loop < node->childrenCount; ++loop) {
        createChild(indent, parent, node, loop);
    }   
    for(int loop = 0; loop < node->childrenCount; ++loop) {
        int status;
        int child = wait(&status);
        for(int ind = 0; ind < indent; ++ind) {
            fprintf(stderr, " ");
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "Parent: %d Reaped %d with status %d\n", parent, child, status);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node* root = makeNode(2);
    root->child[0]   = makeNode(3);
    for(int loopChild = 0;loopChild < 3; ++loopChild) {
        root->child[0]->child[loopChild] = makeNode(3);
        for(int loopGrandChild = 0;loopGrandChild < 3; ++loopGrandChild) {
            root->child[0]->child[loopChild]->child[loopGrandChild] = makeNode(0);
        }
    }
    root->child[1]   = makeNode(4);
    for(int loopChild = 0;loopChild < 4; ++loopChild) {
        root->child[1]->child[loopChild] = makeNode(4);
        for(int loopGrandChild = 0;loopGrandChild < 4; ++loopGrandChild) {
            root->child[1]->child[loopChild]->child[loopGrandChild] = makeNode(0);
        }
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Start\n");
    buildTree(0, getpid(), root);
    fprintf(stderr, "Stop\n");
}
```